# Enable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need write handlers of 2buttons to enable/disable wifi and bluetooth. Now, I can only see phone settings page, where I can change enable/disable wifi and bluetooth manually. So, how can I do it programmatically?

Code for Wi-Fi:

```
        ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
        connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
        connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

other than showing the wifi / Bluetooth settings page, you cannot do anything else.

the user has to then toggle the button.