# How to add new wifi credentials

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an SSID and a password, I'd like to know how to save this new WiFi into the Smartphone known WiFis.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You cannot make those kind of changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668746/enable-wi-fi-and-bluetooth-programmatically

Comment: You should be glad that you cannot make that sort of change

Comment: Hum... Yes, indeed. Or else, behind a yes/no message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so it's possible form code.You must insert it manually form settings menu